# Is there a way to "borrow" the pattern of previous year to forecast for this year?

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting

I have daily data of new member joins from 2017/01/01 to today. I was tasked to perform forecast daily new member joins for the next month (e.g. now is Jan/31, I'm to forecast for the whole Feb).

Preliminary screening shows that:
1) The data has no seasonal component
2) There is no obvious trend (even polynomial ones)
3) The pattern of year 2018 is assumed to follow the pattern of year 2017, and have good correlation (80% between Jan 2018 and Jan 2017)

So far, ARIMA and Holt-Winter do not yield satisfactory results. ARIMA only gives flat line (reasonable, but bad for presentation), and HW doesn't work as well.

I had to choose an intuitive method: Since they have good correlation, I simply calculate the average proportion of year 2018 to year 2017, and apply the result as a multiplier. For example, in average, Jan 2018 new membership joins is around 87.24% of Jan 2017 (daily basis), and I simply multiple 87/24% to Feb 2017 data to predict 2018 data.

The above method somehow works, but I cannot convince myself to take this approach for very long. If I have data of more than one year, I can definitely use ARMA or whatever to capture the annual cycle, but I cannot do so at the moment. Is there a way to make better prediction?
Thank you!

Comment: I am far from an expert in this domain as I have only started getting acquainted with these models, but you may want to look into Gaussian process models. I have had some initial promising results in using these models for imputation in my datasets, which is really it's one kind of forecasting.

Comment: @MattBarstead Thanks for the quick reply! I have not used Gaussian process models before and will definitely look into it. May I know what kind of datasets you have? It was after I dived into real business that I found out that in real world it is pretty difficult to find data without flaws (e.g. my data only has one year plus 31 days, and my manager told me that somehow there are about 2-3 months of data in the middle that are corrupted).

Comment: I am dealing largely with heart rate data. There are sections of it where there is movement artefact that has contaminated the true signal. I am using the surrounding good signal to estimate the sections of bad signal.

Comment: @MattBarstead I actually used multivariate regression for another set of data (same task, but with better quality data) with lots of dummy variables and a couple of semi-continuous variables. The result is only good for forecasting monthly average, not good for daily.

Comment: @MattBarstead I'm using similar methods to "smooth" the corrupted data, sort of "flattening" or "stretching"  the growth factor of same period of previous year and apply on the corrupted data.

Comment: If the data has no seasonal component then why use Jan 2017 to project Jan 2018?